# Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this. Even Prepending bundle exec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to know how to solve the following issue when starting the rails console or server. So far I tried setting the version of the "etc" gem but the solution is not consistent across environments / platforms. Thanks in advance.

```
RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rails console
Traceback (most recent call last):
        9: from /Users/rocks/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        8: from /Users/rocks/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        7: from /Users/rocks/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
        6: from /Users/rocks/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'
        5: from /Users/rocks/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:26:in `setup'
        4: from /Users/rocks/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:26:in `map'
        3: from /Users/rocks/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:148:in `each'
        2: from /Users/rocks/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:148:in `each'
        1: from /Users/rocks/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:31:in `block in setup'
/Users/rocks/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/gems/bundler-2.0.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:319:in `check_for_activated_spec!': You have already activated etc 1.1.0, but your Gemfile requires etc 1.0.1. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
```

Gemfile

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?('/')
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

ruby '2.6.1'
gem 'etc', '1.0.1'
gem 'aws-sdk-s3'
gem 'bcrypt'
gem 'bundler', '>=  2.0.2'
gem 'csv'
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'httparty'
gem 'jwt'
gem 'kaminari-mongoid'
gem 'mailgun-ruby'
gem 'mongoid', ">= 7.0.5"
gem 'mongoid-paperclip'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'one_signal'
gem 'rails', '~>6.0.3.1'
gem 'rails_admin'
gem 'rb-readline'
gem 'redis-store', "1.8.1"
gem 'redis-rails', github: 'redis-store/redis-rails'
gem 'redis', '4.1.4'
gem 'rgeo'
gem 'rmagick', '2.16.0', require: 'rmagick'
gem 'sidekiq', "6.0.7"
gem 'sidekiq-failures'
gem 'sidekiq-uniq'
gem "sidekiq-cron", "~> 1.1"
gem 'simple_enum'
gem 'strava-ruby-client', '~> 0.4.0'
gem 'multi_xml'
gem 'mailgun_rails'
gem 'rack'
gem "passenger", require: "phusion_passenger/rack_handler"
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem "webpacker"
gem 'smarter_csv', '~> 1.2', '>= 1.2.6'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
  gem 'faker', git: 'https://github.com/stympy/faker.git', branch: 'master'
  gem 'listen'
  gem 'railroady'
  gem 'rubocop-performance'
  gem 'solargraph'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'puma'
  gem 'rufo'
end
```

**Bundler**

Bundler version 2.0.2

**rvm**

rvm 1.29.9-next

**$ rvm info**

```
ruby-2.6.1:

  system:
    uname:        "Darwin rockss-MacBook.local 19.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.4.0: Wed Mar  4 22:28:40 PST 2020; root:xnu-6153.101.6~15/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64"
    name:         "OSX"
    version:      "10.15"
    architecture: "x86_64"
    bash:         "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19)"
    zsh:          "/bin/zsh => zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0)"
    remote_path:  "osx/10.15/x86_64"
    xcode:        "11.5"

  rvm:
    version:      "1.29.9-next (master)"
    updated:      "9 months 3 days 23 hours 51 minutes 55 seconds ago"
    path:         "/Users/rocks/.rvm"
    autolibs:     "[4] Allow RVM to use package manager if found, install missing dependencies, install package manager (only OS X)."

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "2.6.1p33"
    date:         "2019-01-30"
    platform:     "x86_64-darwin19"
    patchlevel:   "2019-01-30 revision 66950"
    full_version: "ruby 2.6.1p33 (2019-01-30 revision 66950) [x86_64-darwin19]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/Users/rocks/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1"
    ruby:         "/Users/rocks/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/Users/rocks/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/Users/rocks/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/Users/rocks/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/Users/rocks/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/Users/rocks/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1/bin:/Users/rocks/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1@global/bin:/Users/rocks/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/bin:/Users/rocks/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/rocks/.ebcli-virtual-env/executables:/Users/rocks/flutter/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/Users/rocks/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1"
    GEM_PATH:     "/Users/rocks/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1:/Users/rocks/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.1@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/Users/rocks/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1"
    IRBRC:        "/Users/rocks/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.1/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

Comment: Which bundler version do you use (`bundle -v`) and which version is in your `Gemfile.lock`? You might want to try to delete your `Gemfile.lock` and do a fresh `bundle install`

Comment: are you using rvm/rbenv?

Comment: Hi @ChristianBruckmayer It is bundler 2.0.2. I tried deleting Gemfile.lock . Bundle install successfully installs the gems. But "bundle exec rails console" returns the same error on gem "etc". Thanks

Comment: Hi @jamesc It uses rvm. I have posted the output of "rvm info" Thanks

Comment: Do you really need to use `gem 'etc', '1.0.1'`? The version is from 2018 and there is already a newer version available for more than 1 year. If you remove the `'1.0.1'` it should work (not solving the root cause though).

Comment: Potentially the correct rvm gemset is not being picked up properly. Check that out. Possibly a mismatch between bundler and rvm gemsets. what happens if you try rvm use rubyverion@project_name obviously replacing with actual gemset name

Comment: Hi @ChristianBruckmayer Removing the gem "etc" solves the issue in the local environment / machines. But causes a similar error / halt on production servers. With the following error: 
You have already activated etc 1.0.1, but your Gemfile requires etc 1.1.0. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. Now it works locally and in production.  The issue was solved by checking Gemfile.lock
The issue was caused by the last version of passenger 6.0.5, which introduced a requirement for  the gem "etc".  Using passenger 6.0.2 solved the issue. It does not require gem "etc"

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by checking Gemfile.lock The issue was caused by the last version of passenger 6.0.5 at the time, which introduced a requirement for the gem "etc". Using passenger 6.0.2 solved the issue. It does not require gem "etc"